# Why is generic function crashing when casting to same type?

Tags: swift

Here's some playground code:

```
func getNone<T>() -> T {

    print(T.self)

    let none: Bool? = nil

    return none as! T
}

let noMore: Bool? = getNone()
```

However, this code causes a `found nil while unwrapping optional error`. I'm wondering why this occurs, given `T` in this case is clearly `Bool?` -- from the print statement -- and casting `nil` to `Bool?` doesn't cause this error.

Comment: Why do you want this? `T` could indeed be an optional type, but what if it isn't?

Comment: @Hamish I have a function that returns values from other functions, so instead of casting to the expected return type every time I called it, I decided to use generics and let it infer the type from where it was being called from. Most of those "other" functions return non-optionals, but one returns an optional, so this bug was crashing my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug in Swift to me.  I even added a couple more print statements to highlight this:

```
func getNone<T>() -> T {
    let none: Bool? = nil
    print(type(of: none) == T.self) // prints "true"
    print(none is T) // prints "false". How can that be given the above is true?
    return none as! T // crashes
}

let noMore: Bool? = getNone()
```

---

### UPDATE:

There are a few bugs already filed around similar / related behavior.  For example:

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4248

https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-158

They suggest the same workaround Hamish noted in the comment below. Pretty much confirms that you did indeed stumble on a Swift bug in this case.

Comment: One workaround: `return none as Any as! T`. Looks like the compiler assumes `T` is non-optional, so force unwraps before casting. Casting to `Any` first prevents it from doing that.

Comment: For anyone interested, it was as I suspected; the related type checker code that does this force unwrapping when the source type is more optional than the destination type is here: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/db6b911d4e8c63f530e014c7be7a368bec49a761/lib/Sema/CSApply.cpp#L3336. Really what it should do is skip force unwrapping if the destination type is a less optional generic placeholder (an archetype) and leave that to the runtime as the runtime type may be optional. If I get some time, I'll try and attempt a fix.